# requirejs defining modules not working as expected

Tags: javascript, requirejs, amd

i have the following scenario:

i have a global namespace called fort which has a few common functions that i need and it looks like this :

fort.js

```
define("fort", ["fortHistory"], function (FortHistory) {

  function Fort(){}
    Fort.prototype.history = FortHistory;

    return Fort;
});
```

fortHistory is a small module i created defined as so:

fortHistory.js

```
"use strict";
define("fortHistory", function () {

function FortHistory() {

}
FortHistory.prototype.doSomething = function(){...}
return FortHistory;
});
```

i then do this in my config.js

```
require.config( {
    enforceDefine: true,
    paths: {
        'fort': 'develop/js/fort',
        'fortHistory' : 'develop/js/webapp/fortHistory'
 },
    shim: {
        fort:{
            exports: 'fort'
        }
    }
} );
define( function() {} );
```

finally in main.js i have:

```
define('fort', [], function(fort){
    window.fort = fort;
});
```

the hope was that i could then make a call such as :

```
fort.fortHistory.doSomething();
```

instead fort is undefined so i am assuming i have misinterpreted how requirejs works

Comment: There are several errors here: You are redefining the module called fort in main.js, and you do not have an entry point. Try require('fort', ...) instead of define

Comment: as you said there were a few errors littered around that were sorted, thanks for the heads up

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You've named it `history`, not `fortHistory`:

```
Fort.prototype.history = FortHistory;
```

Try calling it via `fort.history.doSomething();`.